# Installing php extensions onto server without compiler

Tags: php, installation, pecl

I have a couple extensions I need to install on RHEL6.
I've used pecl on my dev and test boxes and it works fine.

However, now I need to install them on my production server, and we don't install any compilers in production.

What's the best way to install the extensions? Can the bits be copied over from my test server (identical build, except with compiler installed)?

Or, can I build it for deployment from my test environment, producing an archive which can just be copied over and un-tar'ed?

Thanks.

Comment: Which extensions? Are they available from the repos? If so, you could just install them with `yum`

Comment: Gearman. It's not available in any repo I've seen.

Comment: FWIW gearmand.x86_64 is in the repos for Fedora 18, albeit just v0.33. You might find [this link](http://eduardo-lago.blogspot.co.nz/2012/07/building-and-packaging-latest-gearman.html) useful